# Orchard 1.8 Slow SQL Performance

Tags: sql, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have deployed an Orchard 1.8 in my production server. The production server is a dedicated server with extremely good specs. Yet the loading time of EACH page is around 3 to 4 seconds which is very slow in our standard. We have over ONE MILLION Content Items and we were under the impression that Orchard is capable of handling such load. Even loading the empty homepage takes that amount of time. So I installed the MiniProfiler module and managed to pinpoint the bottleneck. It is from this SQL query

```
DECLARE @p0 NVARCHAR(4000) = N'Layer'
        ,@p1 BIT = 1;

SELECT this_.Id AS Id1795_2_
        ,this_.Number AS Number1795_2_
        ,this_.Published AS Published1795_2_
        ,this_.Latest AS Latest1795_2_
        ,this_.Data AS Data1795_2_
        ,this_.ContentItemRecord_id AS ContentI6_1795_2_
        ,contentite1_.Id AS Id1794_0_
        ,contentite1_.Data AS Data1794_0_
        ,contentite1_.ContentType_id AS ContentT3_1794_0_
        ,contenttyp2_.Id AS Id1796_1_
        ,contenttyp2_.NAME AS Name1796_1_
FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord this_
INNER JOIN Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite1_ ON this_.ContentItemRecord_id = contentite1_.Id
INNER JOIN Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord contenttyp2_ ON contentite1_.ContentType_id = contenttyp2_.Id
WHERE contenttyp2_.NAME = @p0
        AND this_.Published = @p1
```

I have added indexes for table `Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord` (`Name` column ASC) and table `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord` (`Published` column DESC), but doesn't improve the script execution time.

How do I relieve this bottleneck? This is really a deal breaker, we have spent several months customizing this site for a client which require us to pump in ONE MILLION content items. We're on the verge of scraping the whole project away if this situation can't be remedied. Please help.

**Edit**
I did a test by deploying new instances of Orchard 1.8.1 on both my production server and my development machine. Then pumped both instances with exactly the same one million content items. Next I executed the SQL script above using SQL Server Management Studio on both server and development machine. My production server took more than 2 seconds to retrieve the results while my development machine took less than a second to retrieve the exact same results.

This is weird because my production server is much more powerful than my development machine. The server is a dedicated lean machine running only that Orchard instance, while my development machine besides running the Orchard instance, also has Visual Studio 2013 opened together with 20++ browser tabs. My server has 16GB of RAM while my development machine only has 6GB and the memory usage is at 96% high. The server is running Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server 2014 Entreprise Edition while my development machine is running Windows 7 with SQL Server 2012 Express Edition. The SQL statements Execution Plans for both machines are different too. I'm not really proficient at reading execution plans but I can include the xml version execution plan here if it's necessary.

**Update**
Finally, I'm able to pinpoint that the problem lies with SQL Server. When it comes to execute the above script, SQL Server 2014 query optimizer generated a less than optimal execution plan compared to SQL Server 2012. So my strategy now is to force SQL Server 2014 (production server) to use the execution plan of SQL Server 2012 (development machine).

This is really a problem with SQL Server and not Orchard but since I've already created this question, I might as well share my attempts.
I query the above script in an ad hoc fashion in SQL Server 2014 using the execution plan from SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @p0 NVARCHAR(4000) = N'Layer'
        ,@p1 BIT = 1;

SELECT this_.Id AS Id1795_2_
        ,this_.Number AS Number1795_2_
        ,this_.Published AS Published1795_2_
        ,this_.Latest AS Latest1795_2_
        ,this_.Data AS Data1795_2_
        ,this_.ContentItemRecord_id AS ContentI6_1795_2_
        ,contentite1_.Id AS Id1794_0_
        ,contentite1_.Data AS Data1794_0_
        ,contentite1_.ContentType_id AS ContentT3_1794_0_
        ,contenttyp2_.Id AS Id1796_1_
        ,contenttyp2_.NAME AS Name1796_1_
FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord this_
INNER JOIN Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite1_ ON this_.ContentItemRecord_id = contentite1_.Id
INNER JOIN Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord contenttyp2_ ON contentite1_.ContentType_id = contenttyp2_.Id
WHERE contenttyp2_.NAME = @p0
        AND this_.Published = @p1
OPTION (USE PLAN N'<ShowPlanXML ..... (Execution Plan here)')
```

The query took less than a second to execute which is the desired result. Now, I can't put this execution plan in Orchard core source codes, can I? So I have to create a Plan Guide in SQL Server 2014 and include this Execution Plan. This is what I did

```
EXEC sp_create_plan_guide 
@name = N'Published_Layer_Content_Type',
@stmt = N'SELECT this_.Id AS Id1795_2_
        ,this_.Number AS Number1795_2_
        ,this_.Published AS Published1795_2_
        ,this_.Latest AS Latest1795_2_
        ,this_.Data AS Data1795_2_
        ,this_.ContentItemRecord_id AS ContentI6_1795_2_
        ,contentite1_.Id AS Id1794_0_
        ,contentite1_.Data AS Data1794_0_
        ,contentite1_.ContentType_id AS ContentT3_1794_0_
        ,contenttyp2_.Id AS Id1796_1_
        ,contenttyp2_.NAME AS Name1796_1_
FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord this_
INNER JOIN Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite1_ ON this_.ContentItemRecord_id = contentite1_.Id
INNER JOIN Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord contenttyp2_ ON contentite1_.ContentType_id = contenttyp2_.Id
WHERE contenttyp2_.NAME = @p0
        AND this_.Published = @p1',
@type = N'SQL',
@module_or_batch = NULL,
@params = N'@p0 NVARCHAR(4000), @p1 BIT',
@hints = N'OPTION (USE PLAN N''[Execution Plan here. All single quotes are escaped accordingly]'')'
```

The Plan Guide is created successfully. I've verified that using `SELECT * FROM sys.plan_guides`. However, whenever I execute the query, the Execution Plan wasn't used. What gone wrong? Did I created the Plan Guide wrongly?

Comment: I'm afraid more information is needed. For instance, did you run this query in the SQL query analyzer? If so, what parts of the query are slowing it down? How many layers do you have in the system? Also, if this project is so critical, I would suggest hiring a specialist to look at your project, instead of relying on Stack Overflow...

Comment: I've updated my question to include what I've attempted on two different machines

Comment: Yes, execution plan would be helpful, as well as answers to my other questions, but reading execution plans is not super-hard: you need to look at the percentages and find the parts of the plan that are taking the most time.

Comment: Thanks @BertrandLeRoy for your response. I've updated my question after I've identified that the problem is with different versions of SQL Server and not Orchard.

Comment: This sounds like something that we need to look at in details. It's troubling that 2014 would generate a more inefficient execution plan than 2012. Would you mind opening an issue on https://orchard.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create, with a link to this question?